# Generating multiple columns from 1 column based on their ID,... Access VBA using ADO

Tags: ms-access, vba, ado

I have a table data like so:

ID |  Date | **TIME**

1  |  01/12| 01:00

1  |  01/12| 02:00

1  |  02/12| 03:00

2  |  01/12| 01:00

how to generate multiple columns from column (Time) to be divided like the below result depending on fields ID,Date:

ID |  Date | **Time1** | **Time2** | **Time3** | **Time4**

1  |  01/12| 01:00 | 02:00 | 03:00 | 04:00

1  |  02/12| 01:00 | 02:00 | 03:00 | 04:00

2  |  01/12| 01:00 | 02:00 | 03:00 | 04:00

prefer using ado, loops

Comment: Where does 04:00 come from?

Comment: Asking your question this way won't help you get answer, please don't use "This question is critical" for poorly described problems, it makes people angry about spending their time for a problem they can't solve due to insufficient efforts that you've put in composition of your question. In contrast it should be properly formatted, explicitly defined and raised in clear fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You want to 'pivot' or 'denormalize' data. A CROSSTAB won't generate the headers Time1, Time2, etc because that would require another field with sequence identifier for each ID/Date group. You could do a CROSSTAB that uses the times as column headers. This assumes there is at least one record for each time to generate a column for each time. Also assumes all times are on the hour as shown in your example.

```
TRANSFORM First(Table1.Time) AS FirstOfTime
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Date
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.ID, Table1.Date
PIVOT Table1.Time;
```

Review [Pivot the data from Rows to Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259303/pivot-the-data-from-rows-to-column/43262312#43262312)

Date is a reserved word in Access, should not use reserved words as names for anything.